# Which event should a slider (range) fire to properly work?

Tags: html, css, angular, dom-events

I have the following input, which I converted into a slider:

```
    <div id="slidecontainer">
      <input #ranger type="range" min="{{minInterval}}" max="{{maxInterval}}" step="100" [(ngModel)]="interval"
        (click)="onStart()" class="slider">
    </div>
```

(click) seems to be the wrong angular event. Whenever if drag it and let it go, while the mousepointer is not hovering over the slider, `onStart()` won't get executed.

I tried other events like (dragexit), (mouseup), or whatever, but none worked. When I drag this slider, it sould execute the `onStart()`-method, no matter where the mouse is.

This is my CSS (that shouldn't matter AFAIK):

```
#slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1; /* Fully shown on mouse-over */
}
```

These are the numbers (mentioned in the HTML file) from my component:

```
  interval: number = 3000;
  minInterval: number = 0;
  maxInterval: number = 5000;
```

Comment: (mousedown)="onStart()"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen to changes using the built-in change event just like this:

```
(change)="onStart(ranger.value)"
```

So your input should look like this:

```
 <input #ranger type="range" min="{{minInterval}}" max="{{maxInterval}}" step="100" [(ngModel)]="interval"
        (change)="onStart(ranger.value)" class="slider">
```

Comment: Sweet, I thought "change" would execute whenever the variable changes, not just when you let the slider go. I have a label representing the value of the slider. That one changes on the fly, while (change) only fires on "mouseup" (basically). Thanks!

Comment: Hi, just a side note. We remove salutations here as a matter of course, so please refrain from adding them to your posts. There are many references to this guideline on _Meta_, but the main one [is this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/472495).

Answer (score 2):

Try using onChange or ng-change. Those will trigger whenever the value of the slider is changed, so even if the mouse is moved from the slider the event will activate.

Hope that helps